# Получить индекс из выпадающего списка select

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Как получить индекс из выпадающего списка `select html` в сервлете на java?

Мой код

```
for(int i = 0; i < valute.b.length; i++)
{

    if(valute1.equals(valute.b[i].get("CharCode") + " - " + valute.b[i].get("Name")))
    {

        ch1 = Double.parseDouble(valute.b[i].get("Value").toString()) * Double.parseDouble(valute.b[i].get("Nominal").toString());

    }
    if(valute2.equals(valute.b[i].get("CharCode") + " - "  + valute.b[i].get("Name")))
    {

        ch2 = Double.parseDouble(valute.b[i].get("Value").toString()) * Double.parseDouble(valute.b[i].get("Nominal").toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Для начала необходимо обернуть select в form и прописать сервлет обработчик, а уже в нем получить параметр по названию.

Comment: Это-то я сделал, но как через сервлет получить индекс select?

Comment: Покажите, что Вы сделали, чтоб говорить по существу.

Comment: Я уже по-другому реализовал, но вот код: